# To make wrapfigure work after redefining \par

Tags: paragraphs, incompatibility, wrapfigure, wrap

In my article I need to redefine `\par` so that some variables are reset at the beginning of each paragraph. Then I find that `wrapfigure` does not work. The example code below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\let\paR=\par \def\par{\relax\paR}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}
\begin{ytableau}1&2&3&4\\5&6&7\\8\\9\end{ytableau}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

generates

[image]

and more paragraphs cannot be put below the figure. I also see the following messages: `wrapfigure used inside a conflicting environment on input line 12` and
`Stationary wrapfigure forced to float on input line 16`. How can I make `wrapfigure` work in this situation? Or generally, how can I wrap text around a figure?

Comment: Welcome! Redefining `\par` is probably unwise. Surely there is a safer way to do whatever you are using it for. At least at first glance, this question looks like a classic XY problem. What is the `h` supposed to do exactly?

Comment: As explained in the documentation, `wrapfig` uses the current definition of `\par` to test where it is, comparing it with `\@@par`. It then alters it for the duration of the environment.

Comment: Note that your definition of `\par` is going to be overwritten anyway. So if you just use a list environment before your first `wrapfigure`, it will work fine. A quotation or anything like that will also do the trick. Of course, you lose your redefinition this way. But that's going to happen anyhow.

Comment: @cfr  Sorry, it should be `r` instead of `h`, I have edited it. I don't need any quotation or list environments, but I really need to redefine `\par` (for example, I need to count the number of `\par`s). Also, if `wrapfigure` doesn't work, I need a way that works in my situation.

Comment: @cfr Thank you, I figured it out. The solution is to put the construction ``\begingroup \catcode`\@=11 \def\par{\@par}`` before the `\begin{wrapfigure}` and `\endgroup` after the last wrapped paragraph. However it is still inconvenient and for paragraphs wrapped I need to manually execute those macros inside the redefined `\par`.

Comment: Lists and quotations were just examples. Have you looked at how often LaTeX uses a list? And that is just one place where this runs into trouble. You don't need to redefine `\par`. Whatever you want to do, there is a better way. Of course things are not going to work as they should if you do this. What do you expect? This is just not a good way to do whatever it is. You have one issue now, you think, but there will be more. There are other ways to do wrapped figures, but this is not a good reason to use any of them.

Comment: There are better ways to count the paragraphs. You shouldn't be using `\par` in the body of the document anyway. A blank line is the usual way.

Comment: @cfr a blank line _is_ `\par` this redefines the behaviour of blank lines.

Comment: You should try using \everypar.  Many packages reset \everypar, but wrapfig tries to preserve it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know. But people do surprising things with `\par` which they were not be tempted to do with blank lines.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Are you saying redefining `\par` is a good idea?

Comment: @cfr no `wrapfig` would just be the first of a very long list of things that break.